# JavaScript Function Call Causes "setUTCHours is not a Function"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function

I have some MongoDB records with an OrderDate I wish to update the time component to midnight 00:00:00.000. The object is of the form

```
{
    "SourceSystem" : "XXXX" 
    "OrderDate" : {
        "DateTime" : ISODate("2017-11-29T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
        "Ticks" : 636475104000000000
    }
}
```

To do this I have the following JavaScript

```
function generateDate(targetDateTime){
    let ticks = targetDateTime.getTime() * 10000;
    ticks += 621355968000000000;
    return {
        DateTime: targetDateTime,
        Ticks: NumberLong(ticks)
    };
}

function datePartOnly(targetDateTime){
    targetDateTime.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return generateDate(targetDateTime);
}

let orders = db.Orders.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            State: { $in: [ "Completed", "AwaitingExport" ] }, 
            SourceSystem: "Demon",
            OrderDate: {
                $gte: generateDate(ISODate("20200101")),
                $lt: generateDate(ISODate("20200701"))
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            OrderDateString: {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%H%M%S.%L",
                    date: "$OrderDate.DateTime"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            OrderDateString: /^((?!0{6}\.0{3})[\s\S])*$/
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { _id: 1 }
    }
]).toArray().map( o => o._id );

db.Orders.updateMany(
    {
        _id: { $in : orders }
    },
    {
        $set : {
            OrderDate: datePartOnly("$OrderDate.DateTime")
        }
    }
)
```

but I am getting the following error

> "message" : "targetDateTime.setUTCHours is not a function",
>   "stack" : "script:11:20" +
>             "script:52:24"

Why is this call failing. I have tried using `OrderDate: datePartOnly(ISODate("$OrderDate.DateTime"))` but this gives

> "message" : "invalid ISO date: $OrderDate.DateTime",
>       "stack" : "script:1:37" +
>                 "script:1:37" +
>                 "script:52:37"

`OrderDate: datePartOnly(Date("$OrderDate.DateTime"))` does not work either.

What is wrong with the above?

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue:

---

**Solution:**

Use `new Date()` instead of `Date()`

**Examples:**

1. Using `Date()` only, fails

```
currDate = Date()
// Output: 'Tue Nov 08 2022 12:29:37 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'
currDate.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
// Uncaught TypeError: currDate.setUTCHours is not a function
```

2. Using `new Date()`, passess

NOTE: `new` keyword

```
currDate = new Date()
// Output: Tue Nov 08 2022 12:29:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
currDate.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
// 1667865600000
```

**Reason:**

. `Date()` returns string, see single quotes in 1st `output` above
. `new Date()` returns object correctly, hence `setUTCHours()` works fine

Answer (score 0):

By a small chance, is it possible the argument you are passing as `targetDateTime` is not a Date object (or any type with such function) ? This could explain why `targetDateTime.setUTCHours` is not a valid function.

Comment: It is definitely a DateTime. I though that this could be caused by stringifying the parameter, but wrappig this with ISODate `ISODate("$OrderDate.DateTime")` does not work and neither does `Date("$OrderDate.DateTime")`.

Comment: @CipherShark Exactly, a DateTime, not a Date. I checked MDN and setUTCHours comes from Date (check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours) . Unless ISODate or DateTime inherit from Date type, I think is unlikely to work because the method is simply not there - for what I can see. Even though, I strongly believe this is a data type problem.

Comment: But this works ` function (order) {
        order.OrderDate.DateTime.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        order.OrderDate.Ticks = NumberLong((order.OrderDate.DateTime.getTime() * 10000) + 621355968000000000);
        db.targetCollection.save(order);
        counter++;
    }`